# How to prevent my Viewpager become blank after rotation?

Tags: android

Currently, my ViewPager work like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

but after I rotate the device, my viewpager become blank and have both arrows for every page, like this:

[image]

Here is the code of my activity:

```
public class MainViewPagerHelper {
    private static MainViewPagerHelper sViewPagerHelper = null;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private MainViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    public MainViewPagerHelper(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    public static MainViewPagerHelper getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (sViewPagerHelper == null) {
            sViewPagerHelper = new MainViewPagerHelper(activity);
        }
        return sViewPagerHelper;
    }

    public void dateBarFunction() throws ParseException {


        mDateAreaSlider = (ViewPager) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.date_area);
        adapter = new MainViewPagerAdapter(mActivity, getDateList());
        mDateAreaSlider.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDateAreaSlider.setCurrentItem(adapter.DateList.length - 1);
        mDateAreaSlider.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        mButtonBack = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.btn_back_main);
        mButtonNext = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.btn_next_main);


        // Hide right arrow if reach last position at first launch
        if (mDateAreaSlider.getCurrentItem() == adapter.DateList.length - 1) {
            mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        // Hide left arrow if reach first position at first launch
        if (mDateAreaSlider.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        // Hide both arrows if there is just 1 date
        if (adapter.getCount() == 1) {
            mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        slideToDrawMap();
    }

    public void slideToDrawMap() {
        final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                // Draw map
                String date = adapter.DateList[position].getDate();

                try {

                    // Scroll to item in timeline
                    mTimeLineHelper = TimeLineHelper.getInstance(mActivity);
                    mTimeLineHelper.scrollToDateSelected(date);
                    mDrawMap.drawStayPointAndRoute(date);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (position == adapter.DateList.length - 1) {
                    mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // Hide left arrow if reach first position
                else if (position == 0) {
                    mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // Else show both arrows
                else {
                    mButtonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mButtonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        };
        mDateAreaSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
    }
```

And here is my adapter:

```
public class MainViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public CalendarModel[] DateList;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private RelativeLayout mDateAreaLayoutInflated;

    public MainViewPagerAdapter(Context mContext, CalendarModel[] mDateList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.DateList = mDateList;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position)   {

        //Just instantiate items,nothing special here

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return DateList.length;
    }
```

Please tell me why is this happen and how to solve this.Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but the first code sample is not an Activity.

Comment: It is just an helper class, you can see I passed my activity to it ;). And in my activity, I just call method dateBarFunction()

Comment: Try adding this line to your activity tag in the manifest: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: @user2231822 it worked, but it just use half of my screen when I rotate.Please show me how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but the solution for me was to pass a null bundle in the activity onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null); //otherwise the viewpager is blank on rotation.
    ...
}
```

Looks like the viewpager preserves some values on rotation, and we don't want that.